# Download PDF with IE COM Object

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, pdf, com

I've seem to hit a wall trying to download a PDF file.

Using PowerShells Internet Explorer COM Object, my script logs in to a web site and then navigates to the PDF document. Once on the PDF page, I have tried a couple recommended methods of downloading the file.

1) Using Invoke-WebRequest

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri $PDFUrl -OutFile $Path.pdf
```

2) Pipe the current IE instance to my path, like so:

```
$ie.navigate($url)
Start-sleep -seconds 5
$ie | Out-File $Path.pdf
```

Both methods are outputting invalid PDF's (with no actual content). Am I missing something? Anyone know how I can get the PDF to properly download to my path?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Net.WebClient

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url,$file)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However this did not work either :(  the PDF that downloaded from this was only 2kb and could not be opened with adobe reader. When I open the file with notepad it shows some HTML with a title of "AllRegs Online Server Error". I have a hunch that it is not recognizing me as logged in

Comment: Try with some publicly available documents. If you have something to download behind a login mask, your script Needs to login too.

Comment: Weird, publicly available doc's aren't working either. Tried it with my prior download methods as well (invoke, COM). I may just end up re-writing the script and use Invoke-WebRequest rather than IE COM object.